# Как убрать ошибку если пользователь вводит не тот тип данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, типы-данных

Занимаюсь неделю, написал код калькулятора, не могу понять как сделать чтобы программа не выдавала ошибку если пользователь вводит в числах буквы. Помогите пожалуйста

while 1:

```
what = input('Укажите действие: (+, -, *, /): ')

a = float(input('Первое число: '))
b = float(input('Второе число: '))

if what == '+': c = a + b
elif what == '-': c = a - b
elif what == '*': c = a * b
elif what == '/' and b != 0: c = a / b
elif what == '/' and b == 0:
    print('На ноль делить нельзя')
    continue
else:
    print('Что так сложно следовать инструкциям?')
    continue
print('Ответ: ', c)
```

Comment: Почитайте про исключения и конструкцию `try-except`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про конструкции try-except.
Вот решение:

```
what = input('Укажите действие: (+, -, *, /): ')
try:
    a = float(input('Первое число: '))
    b = float(input('Второе число: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Введен неверный тип данных')
    continue
if what == '+': c = a + b
elif what == '-': c = a - b
elif what == '*': c = a * b
elif what == '/' and b != 0: c = a / b
elif what == '/' and b == 0:
    print('На ноль делить нельзя')
    continue
else:
    print('Что так сложно следовать инструкциям?')
    continue
print('Ответ: ', c)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функцию проверки экземпляра на принадлежность классу:

```
if not isinstance(a, float):
    # ветка если введенное число не типа float
    # обработка неверного ввода
else:
    # когда введенное число типа float
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!